# Neutron in DevStack

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to set up a machine with a single network card running DevStack with Neutron, but shack.sh is failing with

```
2014-12-16 23:39:47.221 | [ERROR] /home/stack/devstack/functions-common:1091 Failure creating private IPv4 subnet for f49997e9027f47fbbe7ea97c9bfd6d62
```

This is the result of trying to execute:

```
neutron subnet-create --tenant-id f49997e9027f47fbbe7ea97c9bfd6d62 --ip_version 4 --gateway 10.0.0.1 --name private-subnet 3c5f8df0-bfd0-4c92-9c8c-fd66fd26fd30 10.11.12.0/24
```

I have tried changing to gateway to 10.11.12.1 and this works.

My local.conf is:

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=192.168.2.54
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.2.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=p2p1

SERVICE_TOKEN=...
ADMIN_PASSWORD=...
MYSQL_PASSWORD=...
RABBIT_PASSWORD=...
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log

LOGDAYS=2

SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta

enable_service tempest
```

I suspect that there are some setting I am missing that control this better. Can anyone advise what these are?

Answer (score 1):

The floating range is actually the external network range. The network gateway needs to be part of this range. There is a separate setting needed to specify the floating IP addresses. I found that the following worked:

```
HOST_IP=192.168.2.54
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.2.0/24
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=p2p1
NETWORK_GATEWAY=10.11.12.1
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=192.168.2.1
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.2.225,end=192.168.2.250
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GATEWAY_NETWORK` is your gateway which is the same IP range with your `HOST_IP`. For example 192.168.2.1